# Store data in tableview to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Tricks.h file

```
#import "Tricks.h"

@implementation Tricks

static NSMutableArray *trickList = nil;

+(NSMutableArray *)trickList
{
    if(!trickList){
        trickList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }
    return trickList;
}

@end
```

Tricks.m file

```
@interface Tricks : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *trickName;
```

Method for adding objects to array

```
-(IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{

    Tricks *trick = [[Tricks alloc]init];
    trick.trickName = self.trickLabel.text;
    [[Tricks trickList]insertObject:trick atIndex:0];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In .h file of UITabelview class I am making a reference to tricks class, but I am sure there is error on this line.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Tricks *tricks;
```

In cellForRow method I am storing data

```
_trick = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:trick,nil];
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:_trick forKey:@"numberArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"%@",_trick);
```

In .m class of UITableview in viewDidLoad I want to retrieve data

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberArray"] != nil) {
        _tricks = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberArray"];

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem ? You are doing right..

Comment: When I remove app from running apps and launch there's no data in table

Comment: @JozefVrana Which notification are you listening for that calls *appWillGoToBackground:* ? Where do you add the observer?

Comment: Still not saving data

Comment: I am storing data in viewDidLoad

Comment: Gee, still no `NSLog()`s! What is the `NSLog` of _trick, add that to your question. It may be nil if `_trick = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:trick,nil];` is not able to create a dictionary. Sure, using `NSLog` is "Caveman debugging" but it works!

Comment: Doesn't your program crash on `_trick = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:trick, nil];` since there is no key provided? I get the following exception: "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil." In any event that like **can not work**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing all the data because you are trying to save Tricks thats is `NSObject` and gets destroyed when your app gets killed, it works while the app is running and you create the `NSUserDefaults` better don't save it as Tricks objects, instead you can store your data as `NSDictionary`, or `NSString` which NSUserDefaults can store, and when you want to use it, you can create `Trick` object using your saved `NSDictionary` data.

**Edit**
Only NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary can be stored using NSUserDefaults

Comment: Updated question with creation of dictionary

Comment: @Jozef that does not create a `NSDictionary`, it is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to `Tricks` that returns an object that `NSUserDefaults` can archive and a method that will restore from that object. Good candidate objects would be `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Perhaps better yet, not knowing much about `Tricks`, add methods to `Tricks` to save and restore to `NSUserDefaults` with an object as above.

If `Tricks` has a substantial amount of information consider `NSCoding` and saving and restoring to a file in the app's `Documents` directory.